# How do I enable cgi-bin directory for Zend

Tags: perl, zend-framework

I have some legacy perl scripts (yes, they are HTML done in perl) that I want to iframe into my Zend application. My preference is to have a /cgi-bin directory under /application that holds the perl scripts. How do I configure Zend to allow access to that directory? It needs to be off doc-root for security, but I want to access it from javascript. If javascript is the wrong way, how can I use a .pl file like a php module to be loaded into an iframe or div?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What *server* are you using? Apache? Are the Perl scripts (F)CGI scripts? Do they produce headers, if so: CGI headers or HTTP headers? Do they produce a standalone HTML page or only a HTML fragment?

Comment: HTML fragments. I want to load them into an iframe or include them on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible use Zend Framework to serve perl scripts, that scripts will be executed with the PHP engine instead of Perl engine.

You'll need setup your Http Server for to serve that scripts specifically.

In Apache you can do it with [`ScriptAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias)